# Alter the table column to change the sequence in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to alter the column present in my oracle database table to use a new sequence that I have created now.

I tried below sql query but it says invalid alter table option.

```sql
alter table doki_data_item2 alter column seq_column set default nextval('new_sequence');
```

Comment: In Oracle, you cannot directly alter a column to use a new sequence as a default value. Instead, you need to add a new column with the desired sequence as the default, update the new column with the existing values, drop the old column, and optionally rename the new column to match the original name.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? There's no need to create new sequence as long as sequence can be altered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax issue.

```
SQL> create sequence first_seq start with 1;

Sequence created.

SQL> create table doki_data_item2(seq_column number default first_seq.nextval);

Table created.

SQL> create sequence second_seq start with 1;

Sequence created.

SQL> alter table doki_data_item2 modify seq_column default second_seq.nextval;

Table altered.
```